# How to check if a variable is an array?

Tags: arrays, variables, awk, gawk, variable-types

I was playing with PROCINFO and its sorted_in index to be able to [control the array transversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal).

Then I wondered what are the contents of `PROCINFO`, so I decided to go through it and print its values:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for (i in PROCINFO) print i, PROCINFO[i]}'
ppid 7571
pgrpid 14581
api_major 1
api_minor 1
group1 545
gid 545
group2 1000
egid 545
group3 10004
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use array `PROCINFO["identifiers"]' in a scalar context
```

As you see, it breaks because there is -at least- one item that it is also an array itself.

The fast workaround is to skip this one:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i in PROCINFO) {if (i!="identifiers") {print i, PROCINFO[i]}}}'
```

However it looks a bit hacky and would like to have something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (i in PROCINFO) {if (!(a[i] is array)) {print i, PROCINFO[i]}}}'
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since there is not a thing like a `type()` function to determine if a variable is an array or a scalar, I wonder: is there any way to check if an element is an array?

I was thinking in something like going through it with a `for` and catching the possible error, but I don't know how.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=1; for (i in a) print i}'
1
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=1; for (i in a) print i}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use scalar `a' as an array
$ awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=1; print a}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: attempt to use array `a' in a scalar context
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GNU Awk, there's an answer, but the recommended approach depends on what version you are running.

---

From GNU Awk 4.2, released in October 2017, there is a new function [`typeof()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Type-Functions) to check this, as indicated in the [release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html) from the beta release:

> 15. The new typeof() function can be used to indicate if a variable or array element is an array, regexp, string or number.  The isarray() function is deprecated in favor of typeof().

So now you can say:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { a[1] = "a"; print typeof(a) }'
array
```

And perform the check as follows:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { a = "a"; if (typeof(a) == "array") print "yes" }'    
$ awk 'BEGIN { a[1] = "a"; if (typeof(a) == "array") print "yes" }'
yes
```

---

In older versions, you can use [`isarray()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Type-Functions.html#Type-Functions):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { a = "a"; if (isarray(a)) print "yes" }'
$ awk 'BEGIN { a[1] = "a"; if (isarray(a)) print "yes" }'
yes
```

From the man page:

```
isarray(x)
    Return true if x is an array, false otherwise.
```

Comment: This is really it! From the manual _isarray() is meant for use in two circumstances. The first is when traversing a multidimensional array: you can test if an element is itself an array or not._, exactly my case!

Comment: From GNU awk 4.2 we now have `typeof()`!

Comment: Nice. We'll add the link to `typeof()` as soon as it gets into the GNU awk docs.