# How to check the type of an awk variable?

Tags: variables, awk, gnu, gawk

The Beta release of gawk 4.2.0, available in http://www.skeeve.com/gawk/gawk-4.1.65.tar.gz is *a major release, with many significant new features*.

I previously asked about [What is the behaviour of FS = " " in GNU Awk 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46609071/1983854), and now I noticed the brand new `typeof()` function to deprecate [`isarray()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414365/1983854):

> Changes from 4.1.4 to 4.2.0
>
> 15. The new `typeof()` function can be used to indicate if a variable or     array element is an array, regexp, string or number. The `isarray()` function is deprecated in favor of `typeof()`.

I could cover four cases: string, number, array and unassigned:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof("a")}'
string
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(1)}'
number
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(a[1])}'
unassigned
$ awk 'BEGIN {a[1]=1; print typeof(a)}'
array
```

However, I struggle to get "regexp" since none of my attempts reach that and always yield "number":

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(/a/)}'
number
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(/a*/)}'
number
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(/a*d/)}'
number
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(!/a*d/)}'
number
$ awk -v var="/a/" 'BEGIN{print typeof(var)}'
string
$ awk -v var=/a/ 'BEGIN{print typeof(var)}'
string
```

How can I get a variable to be defined as "regexp"?

I noticed the previous bullet:

> 14. Gawk now supports strongly typed regexp constants. Such constants     look like @/.../.  You can assign them to variables, pass them to     functions, use them in ~, !~ and the case part of a switch statement.     More details are provided in the manual.

And tried a bit, but with no luck:

```
$ awk -v pat=@/a/ '{print typeof(pat)}' <<< "bla ble"
string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof(/a/)` is running `typeof()` on the result of `$0 ~ /a/` which is a number. I haven't tried this yet myself but I'd expect this to be what you're looking for:

```
typeof(@/a/)
```

and

```
var = @/a/
typeof(var)
```

---

So this works:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print typeof(@/a/)}'
regexp

$ awk 'BEGIN {var=@/a/; print typeof(var)}'
regexp
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{print typeof(@/a/)}'` works and also the other one! I also tried `awk -v var=@/a/ 'BEGIN{print typeof(var)}'` and does not, I wonder how this regexp can be passed properly.

Comment: Did you try quoting it `-v var='@/a/'`? By not quoting it you're exposing it to the shell to do wildcard expansion, etc. When you do `-v var=@/a/` what do you get when you do `print "<" var ">"` in the BEGIN section? It;s also possible that you simply can't assign a regexp constant on the command line and to do what you want should be written as `-v foo="a" 'BEGIN{var=@($0 ~ foo)` or similar.

Comment: Both `awk -v var='@/a/' 'BEGIN{print "<" var ">", typeof(var)}'` and `awk -v var=@/a/ 'BEGIN{print "<" var ">", typeof(var)}'` return the same: "<@/a/> string".

Comment: I am accepting your good answer since it is answering my initial question. What we are commenting here is tangential

Comment: Regarding your suggestion to use `awk -v foo="a" 'BEGIN{var=@($0 ~ foo)}'`, no: `var=@($0 ~ foo)` is not accepted by awk and return a syntax error pointing to the opening parenthesis.

Comment: If you want to get the answer straight from the horse's mouth then you could just ask [in the comp.lang.awk NG](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.awk/UnoZTItfiko/zRzXa7YYBAAJ) and one of the gawk guys (Arnold or Andy or Manuel) will almost certainly respond.